# Make regex work with a character that should not be repeated

Tags: javascript, regex

In my case i need to match user input of domain name that consists of SLD and a TLD (ex: mozzila.com) to a database. I use regex to make some restrictions, but i can't figure out how to make it work with only one dot('.').

`var re = new RegExp ("^[A-Za-z0-9-.]{3,63}$")`
This is my current regex, but it currently works with multiple dots (mozzila....net  works the same as mozzila.net). How can i restrict it to work with just a single dot?

Comment: What about `mozilla.co.uk`

Answer (score 1):

Are only 2 levels allowed?

```
/^[a-z0-9-_]{1,}\.[a-z0-9]{2,}$/i
```

Or deeper one is also ok?

```
/^([a-z0-9-_]{1,}\.){1,}[a-z0-9]{2,}$/i
```

as u/gog noticed with "+" it will be a bit shorter:

```
/^([a-z0-9-_]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,}$/i
```

Comment: I only use the sld's that the user enters, so i dont think i need deeper levels. I just want to make it impossible for the user to enter more than one dot after the SLD.

Comment: `{1,}` is usually written as `+` ;)

Comment: @gog yes, that's true, added to an answer. But tbh, I think `{from, to}` notation makes people think more - which exact count range they expect. Not like I have any statistics, but anecdotic experience with `oh, I've automatically put `+` instead of  `*``.